# In Elder Sign, can I free a focused die?

Tags: elder-sign

If I focus a die, can I free it and reroll it later in the same turn?

The only reference I see in the rules is the following (with something similar in the faq as well):

> Note: A player can focus a die only after a failed roll, and he can focus only once during each of his turns.

This, combined with the "Elder Sign: Omens" iOS game's inability to unfocus a focused die makes me feel it may be set in stone once you focus and bar you from freeing it. Is there any supporting ruling otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.  Once focused, a die may only be used to complete a task using its locked side.**

This is not specifically mentioned in the [rules](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/B1u9FoFcQBS.pdf) or the [FAQ sheet](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Elder%20Sign/support/SL05-faq-web.pdf) - however, based on other rulings in the FAQ, it is clear that not being mentioned in the RAW is not considered proof positive that a rule doesn't exist by the creators.  Focused dice are especially limited in usage, and they seem to be intended to be used only in a very specific way.  I believe you should go with the same ruling as the video game.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added more detail to my post as a result pertaining to what documentation I've found.

Comment: @Joey After reading the FAQ, I have completely changed my answer.  It's still up for interpretation, though.